# Python: get data from a query MS Access with pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x

> Hello, I need your help for this error
> I don’t have experience In Python, I am new on it
> I need to export a query from MS Access to excel
> I create the connection with my database and the connection seems OK
> However, when I call the dataframe from Pandas I have this message:

> Empty DataFrame
> Columns: [Cofor6, TypePce, Ste, CompteDeNfact]
> Index: []

> This is my code:

`connection_string = (`
r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
r"DBQ=C:\xxx\xx\Python_Projects\xxx\xx\xx\mydb.mdb;"
r"ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;")`

`connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create("access+pyodbc",query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})`

`engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)`

`print ('connected')`

`RAFAELquery= '''SELECT SAP_CONSO.Cofor6,SAP_CONSO.TypePce,SAP_CONSO.Ste,Count(SAP_CONSO.Nfact) AS CompteDeNfact FROM SAP_CONSO GROUP BY SAP_CONSO.Cofor6,SAP_CONSO.TypePce,SAP_CONSO.Ste,SAP_CONSO.SaiParFlux HAVING (((SAP_CONSO.TypePce) Not Like 'y\*') AND ((SAP_CONSO.SaiParFlux) Like '\*E')) ORDER BY SAP_CONSO.TypePce DESC;'''`

`df=pd.read_sql_query(RAFAELquery,engine)`

`print(df)`

> Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: I found my error, I simply replaced the "*" in my query by % and python returns me the dataframe that I wanted.